# Correct use of passive

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, passive

> Er sagte, dass die Reise beantragt werden müssen, bevor sie reisen
>   können.
>
> He said that the travel must be applied for before they can travel.

Is this the correct use of passive?

I’m always confused when I have to use the passive voice.

Answer (score 6):

With indirect speech, it is always best to first find out how the sentence would have looked like in direct speech. This determines the form that needs to be taken when transformed into indirect speech.

The speaker could have said:

> "Die Reise muss beantragt werden, bevor ..." (1)

or he could have said:

> "Die Reise müsste beantragt werden, bevor ..." (2)

(1) translates to *Konjunktiv I* in indirect speech, such as

> Er sagte, die Reise müsse beantragt werden, bevor ...

while (2) is already Konjunktiv in direct speech, so that transforms (or rather not) into

> Er sagte, die Reise müsste beantragt werden, bevor ...

Both forms are possible and correct.

Comment: It could be added that the first variant corresponds to the English translation in the question.

Answer (score 1):

"Er sagte, dass die Reise beantragt werden müss**te**, bevor sie reisen können."

as it is only one travel you need to use the singular. multiple travels would be:
"Er sagte, dass die Reise**n** beantragt werden müssen, bevor sie reisen können."

edit after the comments:
as far as you use Konjunktiv, which I use in the singular, it is correct to use **müssten** in the plural sentence.

In this case you might ommit the Konjunktiv as the statement is in no doubt but a fix rule. So the plural sentence is possible with **müssen**, but then also the singular with **muss**.

Comment: If you opt for Konditional, *müsste*, shouldn't it be *müssten* in the plural? In any case, Konjunktiv, i.e. *müsse*, appears more fitting, with this being indirect discourse.

Comment: I too would suggest Konjunktiv I, i.e. **müsse**.

Comment: Wieso nicht "muss"?

Comment: Wieso nicht _muss_? Weil indirekte Rede in der Regel mit Konjunktiv I (und nicht dem Indikativ) wiedergegeben wird, jedenfalls außerhalb der Umgangssprache.

Comment: IMHO: "Er sagte, die Reise muss beantragt werden", "Er sagte sie müsste beantragt werden, wenn man länger als 3 Tage verreist", "Er sagte sie müsse beantragt werden, aber das Gesetz sagt etwas anderes."

Comment: Das erste Beispiel ist nur in der direkten Rede (Er sagte: "Die Reise muss beantragt werden.") richtig, sonst umgangssprachlich.

Comment: @Ingmar: Das ist in der Tat ein mehrdeutiger Fall: Bei "Er sagte, dass die Reise beantragt werden müsse." wird mittels indirekter Rede ausgedrückt, was er gesagt hat (unabhängig vom Wahrgeitsgehalt der Aussage). In "Er sagte, dass die Reise beantragt werden muss." wird ohne indirekte Rede die Tatsache zum Ausdruck gebracht, die er verkündet (ohne einen genaueren Hinweis darauf zu liefern, in welcher Form dies geschah).